# Android: displaying long text for TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to display a long text about 250 chars (single line, no new line chars. or breaks). for a TextView of my activity.

I have used textType as textMultiLine for my layout's view and from activity I used view.setText() method by passing the long text.

But the text is displaying out of the visible screen.

How to fix this?

Thanks,
Nehatha

+++ Edit +++++

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/bg" 
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/rootView">
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:minWidth="310dp" android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">


                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tabContentPostDetails"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/transparent_border_shape">
                        <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">
                            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/csPostTitle"
                                    android:padding="3dip" android:textSize="7pt"
                                    android:textColor="@color/Black"  
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </TableRow>

                        ....
```

Comment: Have you found the right answer eventually?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using `layout_width="wrap_content"`. This will make the TextView stretch to contain your text in a single line. Try using `layout_width="fill_parent"` (or a given width), and `layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Comment: Hi Gregory, I have tried with "fill_parent" but still i'm not seeing the entire text.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you have and your layout ?

Comment: Hi Gregory, i have updated my original post with my layout code snippet, please check @+id/csPostTitle view.

Answer (score 2):

try `android:maxEms="15"` .i think it will help you

Comment: Perfect solution! when appending text to the same TextView and you want to restrict the number of letters in any given line within the View.

Answer (score 2):

What helped me in this situation, was setting `layout_gravity="fill_vertical"` like this:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_e_taskdesc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:text="@string/empty_label1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following attributes for the textview:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:maxLines="10"
```

Change 10 to whatever number works for you.

The layout I tested was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/rootView">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:minWidth="310dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabContentPostDetails"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="#ffffff">
                        <TableRow 
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                            android:background="#ff0000"
                            >
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/csPostTitle"
                                android:background="#00ff00"
                                android:padding="3dip"
                                android:textSize="7pt"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                                android:maxLines="10"
                                android:text="this is a very long text. so long that it does not ghave any breaks whasoever. this is a test to see if the line dissplayes proper;ly." />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Mandel, this is not working for me, still the text is displaying in a single line and i'm not able to see the text that is out of the visible screen.

Comment: See the layout I tested. Perhaps, there is some other change I forgot to mention. Compare the above layout with the one you have.